# devise and invitable plugin : how do you set the invitation_limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi ive got devise and the invitable plugin working but Id like to set a default limit on how many people a user can invite.

According to the documentaion on github it mentions that you can set this number via invitation_limit

however ive tried using this in devises config file but it complains of undefined method.

I checked the source and theres definately an invitation_limit attribute being decremented. I tried adding this as an attribute to my users model but it still complains.

How do you setup this up????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the version of the devise_invitable gem that does not include "invitation_limit." You will need to use at least v0.4.rc5 to get all the new coolness that the documentation talks about. It's definitely a little confusing. Your Gemfile should look like this:

```
gem 'devise', '~>1.2.0'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~>0.4.rc5'
```

See here for a more in depth write-up about this issue with [devise_invitable](http://andrewgertig.com/2011/03/making-your-rails-web-app-invite-only-using-devise_invitable/).

Comment: as we say in england, "you sir are a legend".